# FIREBASE: Missing ability to select apps under on Project

Tags: firebase

Firebase used to have the ability to choose an app under Analytics, now that is missing.  How would I get all my individual stats per app.  This was here I want to say a month or so ago, but now it's missing.  The drop down option is still available Crashlytics and Performance, but is missing in Analytics.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There was a major update to the Analytics dashboard in the Firebase console about a month ago. You can read all about it in the blog post [Improving the Google Analytics dashboard in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70010516/firebase-missing-ability-to-select-apps-under-on-project) and in the Help Center page on [New Google Analytics 4 functionality in Google Analytics for Firebase](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/11091821).

From what I understand, filters such as the one for a specific app, are now part of the [Comparisons feature](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9269518) of Google Analytics.